# Revtex4-2-How to make the abstract a wide text during using twocolumn

Tags: revtex, abstract, wide

I need to have the abstract part in a wide-text version but not the rest. I've tried

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\frontmatter@abstractwidth{\dimexpr\textwidth-1in\relax}
\makeatother
```

but this did not change anything, I tried some other advice from other questions but nothing did work.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,twocolumn,aps,pra, superscriptaddress,longbibliography]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\captionsetup{
  subrefformat=parens
}

\begin{document}
\date{\today}

\author{Figen Yilmaz}
\author{C...}
\title{blabla}

\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{Abstract}
```

Like in this image:
[image]
But I would like to have the title 'abstract'
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\renewcommand\frontmatter@abstractwidth` was completely right, you'll just have to use the `abstract` environment for your abstract:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,twocolumn,aps,pra, superscriptaddress,longbibliography]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\captionsetup{
  subrefformat=parens
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\frontmatter@abstractwidth{\dimexpr\textwidth\relax}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\date{\today}

\author{Figen Yilmaz}
\author{C...}
\title{blabla}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was really informative and it worked!

Comment: @FigenYILMAZ You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The abstract should go *before* `\maketitle`.

I'd prefer a different way to redefine `\frontmatter@abstractwidth`, because this should be a macro expanding to a dimension. You don't want to subtract 1in, though.

I'd not worry, though: the class doesn't provide for the details that will be added during the publishing phase, including the format for the abstract they prefer.

Note that `caption` (and `subcaption`) are not compatible with `revtex4-2` and using them would change the appearance of captions, which won't please the copy editors at the journal you're submitting the paper to. You can use instead `subfig` as shown below.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,twocolumn,aps,pra, superscriptaddress,longbibliography]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% also loads graphicx
%\usepackage{subcaption}% incompatible with revtex4-2
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%\captionsetup{
%  subrefformat=parens
%}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\edef\frontmatter@abstractwidth{\the\textwidth}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\date{\today}

\author{Figen Yilmaz}
\author{C...}
\title{blabla}

\date{\today}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[3]
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum

\begin{figure*}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}

\caption{A double subfloat}

\end{figure*}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]